# Does creating a screen in Storyboard write code to files in navigator?

Tags: ios, storyboard

When you create a new screen in Storyboard, does it modify the code that appears in the files in the navigator pane? If so, where?

I understand that when you modify code in the files, it changes what appears in XIB (the Storyboard). However, I have added a new screen in Storyboard by dragging over the object and I don't see a new view controller or place where any code is getting written in the navigator pane.  When I compile, the new screen appears if I check `Is Initial View Controller`.

I cannot find anything in Apple's documentation or any tutorials. I presume some code was written somewhere by creating a new screen, but I don't know where.

Note: I am not working in a completely blank project but rather a starter project in a tutorial.  It already has a couple of view controllers for different pages but nothing new (that I can find) appears when I create the new screen.

Comment: The answer to your question is no, it does not modify any of the files in the navigator pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a view controller to the storyboard, all it does is edit the .storyboard file to now include this UI element that you added.  By default, the class for this view controller will be of type UIViewController.  If you want to write code which effects this new element you added, you have to add files manually to your project.  Search "How to subclass UIViewController".  Once you add the proper .m and .h files for your UIViewController subclass, head over to the .storyboard file, click on the element you added and in the right pane, set its class as your subclass that you made.

Edit: Some screenshots to guide you in the process

File->new->File->Cocoa Touch Class
[image]

subclass of should be UIViewController, class is whatever you want it to be
[image]

In .storyboard file click on the view controller element you added and edit its class in the right pane, set it to the same as the new class you generated.
[image]

Comment: is .storyboard an actual file in the usual sense that you edit in Objective C or just this visual representation.

Comment: @user1904273, it's an XML file; it isn't written in Objective-C. You can see it by right clicking on the storyboard file, and choosing Open As Source Code.